# XMLHttp request to 302 page

Tags: javascript, browser, xmlhttprequest

I need to send an xmlhttprequest to a page that returns 302 and redirects and not to the redirected page,
I saw this :
[Problems with xmlhttprequest status 302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524039/problems-with-xmlhttprequest-status-302)

but this solution only works in Firefox, i need something that will work for IE and Chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure this is possible, sadly - I think the spec for `XMLHttpRequest`s says they should follow redirects.

Comment: Will this be running on clients with Flash?  It would be a bit of a hack, but you could replace XMLHttpRequest with something that called through to Flash to do the actual request, giving you a bit more control.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible to do client-side with JS.  `XMLHttpRequest`s follow redirects silently.

Would it work to use the server as a proxy?  So you would make a request to `"/utils/inspectRedirect?url=..."`, and it would return you something like:

```
{
    "originalUri": ...,
    "redirectUri": ...,
    "httpCode": 302
}
```

If you don't need the full data, just the redirect URI, then this shouldn't place any strain on the server (it can just make a HEAD request).

Comment: i just need the url but i have no access to the server and it could be different servers... i just need to know which page is sending the redirect... you can see it with fiddler so the client knows about it, why cant i get this information with js ?

Comment: Because of the defined behaviour for XMLHttpRequests.  The closest you get is mention of a possible *future* "property to disable following redirects" in the [existing spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20080415/#notcovered).  If you need to track redirects, then a pure JS client-side solution using XMLHttpRequest is not possible.