# Angular: channel.redirectionLimit in $http?

Tags: http, angularjs, oauth, xmlhttprequest

So I'm doing this OAuth request that responds with a 302 redirect and I need to actually process it and perform the redirect manually. I know that your standard $http.get in Angular will not return the Location header since the XMLHttpRequest blindly follows the redirect, but I'm looking for a way to bypass this behaviour. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524039/problems-with-xmlhttprequest-status-302) I found out that you can get the location header by disabling redirects on the HTTP channel such as:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();    
req.open("GET","http://www.megaupload.com/?d=6CKP1MVJ",true);
req.channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel).redirectionLimit = 0;
req.send(null);
```

Is there a lower level angular object that allows redirectionLimit to be set? Or perhaps another way to hack it so that I won't have to resort to the actual XMLHttpRequest object? Thanks.

Comment: If you re doing oauth u may have a referer un the header no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`XMLHttpRequest.channel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#channel) stuff is non-standardized and Firefox-only, and then only available for privileged code (add-ons, but not web sites).

Since the `XMLHttpRequest` that web content gets does not provide a `redirectionLimit` feature, AngularJS cannot provide such a feature either.